# How to block the auto append of architecture(x86_64) in rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build an RPM using rpmbuild on RHEL 8.4 OS. All the details related to RPM are given in a SPEC file. In the stage of "Processing file", architecture(x86_64) is automatically appended at the end of N-V-R.

> Processing file : Application-Server-10.2.0-3.x86-64.

Post that, I have added "**BuildArch: noarch**" in the SPEC file to block the architecture. But the result was,

> Processing file : Application-Server-10.2.0-3.noarch

This addition of architecture leads to some errors like "File Not found" and finally got the error as "usr/bin/rpmbuild failed with exit code 1".

And the SPEC file is like,

```
# Version
Name : ApplicationServer
Version : 10.2.0
Release : 3
License : xxxx
BuildArch: noarch

%description
Application Server

%files
%defattr(0755,xxx,xxx)
%attr(0755,xxx,xxx) /jboss
%changelog
```

And the final error was,

```
CreateRPM:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /root/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/work/SPECS
      [rpm] Building the RPM based on the xxxx.spec file
      [rpm] Processing files: ApplicationServer-10.2.0-3.x86_64
      [rpm]
      [rpm]
      [rpm] RPM build errors:
      [rpm] error: File not found: /root/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/work/BUILDROOT/ApplicationServer-10.2.0-3.x86_64/jboss
      [rpm]     File not found: /root/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/work/BUILDROOT/ApplicationServer-10.2.0-3.x86_64/jboss
      [rpm] '/usr/bin/rpmbuild' failed with exit code 1
```

Please let me know the workaround solution.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us things like the specfile, what files are left in the build staging area, etc. Otherwise, we don't have anything to go on.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco..Please have a look at the Question.  I have added the spec file.

Comment: Still nowhere near enough info to go on. You're saying your package owns everything in `/jboss` including the directory itself; this is likely wrong.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco..But the above code works fine on RHEL 5.6. In RHEL 8.4 am facing the above error. Please have look at the final error section. Kindly let me know if any details are needed.

Comment: `File not found: /root/` **Don't build RPMs as root. Ever.** Even more so if you're writing your own specfiles - you may have nuked your entire machine. That said, I've answered as much as I can, as has @msuchy. Your build process didn't put `jboss` where your specfile says it would be.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way how to get rid of the arch part during the rpmbuild phase, but...

The resulting file is just a file. It can have any name. You can

```
mv Application-Server-10.2.0-3.noarch.rpm EvenMoreCoolApplication-Server-10.2.0-3.rpm
```

and then

```
rpm -Uvh EvenMoreCoolApplication-Server-10.2.0-3.rpm
```

And rpm (or DNF) will install it from this file. Though, they will print something like "installing Application-Server".

Comment: @msuchy..Thank you. While in the middle, I can't able to execute the "mv" command. The build starts from the command.."<rpm topdir="directoryName" specfile="fileName"/>".  Please have a look at the final error section in the above post.